# How to use PyCharm to debug Scrapy projects

Tags: python, debugging, python-2.7, scrapy, pycharm

I am working on Scrapy 0.20 with Python 2.7. I found PyCharm has a good Python debugger. I want to test my Scrapy spiders using it. Anyone knows how to do that please?

#### What I have tried

Actually I tried to run the spider as a script. As a result, I built that script. Then, I tried to add my Scrapy project to PyCharm as a model like this:

```
File->Setting->Project structure->Add content root.
```

But I don't know what else I have to do

Answer (score 204, accepted):

The `scrapy` command is a python script which means you can start it from inside PyCharm.

When you examine the scrapy binary (`which scrapy`) you will notice that this is actually a python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from scrapy.cmdline import execute
execute()
```

This means that a command like 
`scrapy crawl IcecatCrawler` can also be executed like this: `python /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py crawl IcecatCrawler`

Try to find the scrapy.cmdline package.
In my case the location was here: `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py`

Create a run/debug configuration inside PyCharm with that script as script. Fill the script parameters with the scrapy command and spider. In this case `crawl IcecatCrawler`.

Like this:
[image: PyCharm Run/Debug Configuration]

Put your breakpoints anywhere in your crawling code and it should work™.

Comment: (<type 'exceptions.SyntaxError'>, SyntaxError("Non-ASCII character '\\xf3' in file /Library/python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.pyc on line 1, but no encoding declared;

Comment: @AymonFournier:  Different problem, not related to the original question. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589620/syntaxerror-non-ascii-character-xa3-in-file-when-function-returns-£

Comment: Great solution!
I also tried using the scrapy binary itself located mostly in: /usr/bin/scrapy as the script with same parameters or any other scrapy commands you want to debug and it worked just perfect.

make sure the working directory is pointing to your scrapy project root where scrapy.cfg is located.

Comment: @AymonFournier It seems you are trying to run a .pyc file. Run the corresponding .py file instead (scrapy/cmdline.py).

Comment: If I'm doing that, my settings module is not found. 
`ImportError: No module named settings`
I have checked that the working directory is the project directory.
It's used within a Django project. Anyone else stumbled upon this problem?

Comment: Using this method, the configuration for scrapy seems to be ignored. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Not forget to config `Working directory`, otherwise will error `no active project, Unknown command: crawl, Use "scrapy" to see available commands, Process finished with exit code 2`

Comment: it says : from scrapy.http.headers import Headers ImportError: cannot import name 'Headers' from partially initialized module 'scrapy.http.headers most likely due to a circular import Python38

Answer (score 123):

You just need to do this.

Create a Python file on crawler folder on your project. I used main.py.

- Project

  - Crawler

    - Crawler

      - Spiders
      - ...
    - **main.py**
    - scrapy.cfg

Inside your main.py put this code below.

```
from scrapy import cmdline    
cmdline.execute("scrapy crawl spider".split())
```

And you need to create a "Run Configuration" to run your main.py.

Doing this, if you put a breakpoint at your code it will stop there.

Comment: You might want to configure multiple executions for different spiders, so accept spider name as an argument of your run config. Then 
    import sys

    spider = sys.argv[1]

    cmdline.execute("scrapy crawl {}".format(spider).split())

Comment: @miguelfg, can you elaborate on how to pass a spider name as an argument in run config without doing so manually each time you run the project?

Answer (score 50):

As of 2018.1 this became a lot easier. You can now select `Module name` in your project's `Run/Debug Configuration`. Set this to `scrapy.cmdline` and the `Working directory` to the root dir of the scrapy project (the one with `settings.py` in it).

Like so:

[image: PyCharm Scrapy debug configuration]

Now you can add breakpoints to debug your code.

Answer (score 12):

I am running scrapy in a virtualenv with Python 3.5.0 and setting the "script" parameter to `/path_to_project_env/env/bin/scrapy` solved the issue for me.

Comment: I'm suprised this works, I thought scrapy didn't work with python 3

Comment: Thanks, this worked with Python 3.5 and virtualenv. "script" as @rioted said and setting "working directory" to `project/crawler/crawler`, i.e., the directory holding `__init__.py`.

Answer (score 6):

**intellij idea** also work.

create **main.py**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#coding=utf-8
import sys
from scrapy import cmdline
def main(name):
    if name:
        cmdline.execute(name.split())



if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('[*] beginning main thread')
    name = "scrapy crawl stack"
    #name = "scrapy crawl spa"
    main(name)
    print('[*] main thread exited')
    print('main stop====================================================')
```

show below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I am also using PyCharm, but I am not using its built-in debugging features.

For debugging I am using [`ipdb`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb). I set up a keyboard shortcut to insert `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` on any line I want the break point to happen.

Then I can type `n` to execute the next statement, `s` to step into a function, type any object name to see its value, alter execution environment, type `c` to continue execution...

This is very flexible, works in environments other than PyCharm, where you don't control the execution environment.

Just type in your virtual environment `pip install ipdb` and place `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` on a line where you want the execution to pause.

UPDATE

You can also `pip install pdbpp` and use the standard `import pdb; pdb.set_trace` instead of `ipdb`. PDB++ is nicer in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

To add a bit to the accepted answer, after almost an hour I found I had to select the correct Run Configuration from the dropdown list (near the center of the icon toolbar), then click the Debug button in order to get it to work. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    # Your spider definition
    ...

process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
})

process.crawl(MySpider)
process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

Answer (score 3):

Might be a bit late, but maybe it helps somebody:

Since the latest PyCharm-versions it's actually pretty straight forward, you can call Scrapy directly - see attached picture of runtime config (Scrapy tutorial).

Tested with PyCharm 2022.1.4.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I use this simple script:

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())

process.crawl('your_spider_name')
process.start()
```

Comment: I use something similar to this called `runner.py`. The reason this is important is because it intentionally loads the project settings file. You must do this if you are trying to load pipeline(s).

Answer (score 0):

Extending @Rodrigo's version of the answer I added this script and now I can set spider name from configuration instead of changing in the string.

```
import sys
from scrapy import cmdline

cmdline.execute(f"scrapy crawl {sys.argv[1]}".split())
```