# Debugging Scrapy Project in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, scrapy, visual-studio-code

I have Visual Studio Code on a Windows Machine, on which I am making a new Scrapy Crawler. The crawler is working fine but I want to debug the code, for which I am adding this in my `launch.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "Scrapy with Integrated Terminal/Console",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "stopOnEntry": true,
    "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
    "program": "C:/Users/neo/.virtualenvs/Gers-Crawler-77pVkqzP/Scripts/scrapy.exe",
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "args": [
        "crawl",
        "amazon",
        "-o",
        "amazon.json"
    ],
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "env": {},
    "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
    "debugOptions": [
        "RedirectOutput"
    ]
}
```

But I am unable to hit any breakpoints.
PS: I took the JSON script from here: http://www.stevetrefethen.com/blog/debugging-a-python-scrapy-project-in-vscode

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use PyCharm to debug Scrapy projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21788939/how-to-use-pycharm-to-debug-scrapy-projects)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In order to execute the typical `scrapy runspider <PYTHON_FILE>` command you must to set the following config into your `launch.json`:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Launch Scrapy Spider",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "scrapy",
            "args": [
                "runspider",
                "${file}"
            ],
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

Set the breakpoints wherever you want and then debug.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Adding a scrapy-specific configuration in the working-project's `launch.json` is a good practice, easy to implement and doesn't require an additional script to be created.

Comment: @cpinamtz This doesn't seem to work for me for whatever reason. I use a very similar set up, the program runs, but doesn't stop at the break points.

Comment: @Asif in case you're using multiple spiders, check you're executing the one you expect to debug

Comment: Link to Scrapy documentation that uses the above config: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/debug.html#visual-studio-code

Answer (score 22):

1. Inside your scrapy project folder create a `runner.py` module with the following:

   ```
   import os
   from scrapy.cmdline import execute

   os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))

   try:
       execute(
           [
               'scrapy',
               'crawl',
               'SPIDER NAME',
               '-o',
               'out.json',
           ]
       )
   except SystemExit:
       pass
   ```
2. Place a breakpoint in the line you wish to debug
3. Run `runner.py` with vscode debugger

Answer (score 9):

Configure your `json` file like that:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Crawl with scrapy",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "module": "scrapy",
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "args": [
            "crawl",
            "<SPIDER NAME>"
        ],
        "console": "internalConsole"
    }
]
```

Click on the tab in VSCode corresponding to your spider, then launch a debug session corresponding to the `json` file.

Comment: this one is the most updated answer as it uses the newest scrapy crawl command.

Answer (score 5):

You could also try with

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Scrapy",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "module": "scrapy",
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "args": [
            "crawl",
            "${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "--loglevel=ERROR"
        ],
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "justMyCode": false
    }
  ]
}
```

but the name of the field should be the same than the spiders name.

The --loglevel=ERROR is to get an output less verbose ;)

Comment: To make `crawl` works with `${fileBasenameNoExtension}`, make sure that spider class `name` attribute has the same value as script file basename.

Answer (score 3):

I made it. The simplest way is to make a runner script `runner.py`

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

from g4gscraper.spiders.g4gcrawler import G4GSpider

process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'json',
    'FEED_URI': 'data.json'
})

process.crawl(G4GSpider)
process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

Then I added breakpoints in the spider while I launched debugger on this file.
Reference: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html

Answer (score 2):

I applied @fmango's code and improve it.

1. Instead of write a seperated runner file, just paste these code lines at the end of spider.
2. run python debugger. that's all

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os
    from scrapy.cmdline import execute

    os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))

    SPIDER_NAME = MySpider.name
    try:
        execute(
            [
                'scrapy',
                'crawl',
                SPIDER_NAME,
                '-s',
                'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING=utf-8',
            ]
        )
    except SystemExit:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't need to modify the launch.json, the default "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)" works perfectly. For the Python3 project, remember to place the runner.py file at the same level as the **scrapy.cfg** file (which is the project root).

The runner.py code as @naqushab does above. Note the **processs.crawl(*className*)**, where the ***className*** is the spiders class that you want to set the breakpoint at.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer leverages the `launch.json` provided by Scrapy's documentation. However, depending on where and how you are running your scrapers, you may not have the scrapy module available. Here is an alternative method that connects on your localhost and port, and allows for debugging with Python's `debugpy`. The example I provide is specifically for debugging spiders, but it may work for other scrapy objects as well.

Python version: 3.11.0

```json
# launch.json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Attach",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "attach",
            "connect": {
                "host": "localhost",
                "port": 5678
            },
            "justMyCode": false
        }
    ]
}
```

At the bottom of whatever Spider you are running, include the following:

```py
# foo_bar_spider.py

class FooBarSpider():
  ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import debugpy
    print('waiting for client...')
    debugpy.listen(('localhost', 5678)) # should be the port you're using
    debugpy.wait_for_client()
    from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(FooBarSpider)
    process.start()
    process.join()
```

Lastly, you can use Python to execute the file (e.g. `python foo_bar_spider.py`) and you should see the "wait for client" printed in your terminal. Go ahead and launch the VSCode debugger, and you should be good to go.