# Scrapy crawl: Crawled 0 pages

Tags: python, scrapy

I am creating a simple scrapy project to better understand how to use it, and what I intend to do is crawl the questions page for StackOverflow.

My spider is called `first` and here's the content of the file.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class FirstSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'first'
    allowed_domains = ['stackoverflow.com']
    start_urls = ['https://stackoverflow.com/questions']

    rules = (
            Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['/questions/\?page=\d&sort=newest']), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = scrapy.Item()

        selector_list = response.css('.question-summary')

        for selector in selector_list:
            item['question'] = selector.css('h3 a::text').extract()
            item['votes'] = selector.css('.vote-count-post strong::text').extract()
            item['answers'] = selector.css('.status strong::text').extract()
            item['views'] = selector.css('.views::text').extract()
            item['username'] = selector.css('.user-details a::text').extract()
            item['user-link'] = selector.css('.user-details a::attr(href)').extract()

        return item
```

It should then traverse the pages of the questions gathering the info.

I can get the data from the shell but fail when I try to crawl or save the output.

Here's the output of `scrapy crawl first`:

```
2018-04-07 13:57:06 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.0 started (bot: scraper)
2018-04-07 13:57:06 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.1.0, libxml2 2.9                                                               .5, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.4.0, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 17.9.0, Python 2.7.14 (                                                               v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:19:30) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)], pyOpenSS                                                               L 17.5.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018), cryptography 2.2.2, Platform Windows-XP-                                                               5.1.2600-SP3
2018-04-07 13:57:06 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODU                                                               LE': 'scraper.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['scraper.spiders'], 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY':                                                                True, 'BOT_NAME': 'scraper'}
2018-04-07 13:57:06 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2018-04-07 13:57:07 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2018-04-07 13:57:07 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2018-04-07 13:57:07 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2018-04-07 13:57:07 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-04-07 13:57:07 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pag                                                               es/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-04-07 13:57:07 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening o                                                               n 127.0.0.1:6023
2018-04-07 13:57:08 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2018-04-07 13:57:09 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://stackoverflow.com/questions> (referer: None)
2018-04-07 13:57:09 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2018-04-07 13:57:09 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 502,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 35092,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 7, 10, 57, 9, 609000),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 7, 10, 57, 7, 625000)}
2018-04-07 13:57:09 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: Have you tried `extract_first()`? If you are using pycharm, why not put a debug point before `return item`, here is how. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21788939/how-to-use-pycharm-to-debug-scrapy-projects

Comment: replacing with `extract_first` and adding `extract` to `selector_list` returns the same list.

Comment: replace the `return item` with `yield item`. ^_^

Comment: the crawl still doesn't happen `2018-04-07 15:53:43 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
` it doesn't even crawl the first page.

Comment: Can you post your `CrawlSpider` code?

Comment: I think maybe you need to define your items in `items.py` field, you can refer to this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/48918265/8389458

Answer (score 1):

Item fields should be defined in the `items.py` like described here (otherwise there will be `KeyError`): https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html#declaring-items.

In your case above item needs to be created and yielded within a loop (not outside). Like:

```
for selector in selector_list:
    item = QuestionItem()
    item['question'] = selector.css('h3 a::text').get()
    ...
    yield item
```

Also, consider using item loaders to populate items: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html

Comment: used this but it still doesn't perform a crawl.

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to detect a problem without looking at the code (provided code example won't work for several reasons). Based on scrapy logs everything is okay with the spider, problem only with parsing the response and returning items.

Comment: Also try `parse` callback, not `parse_item`.

Comment: After a bit of back and forth got it working. Now dealing with how to query specific links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49728311/scrapy-traverse-other-links

Comment: @SamB. What exactly got it working?  I'm facing this exact same problem right now... INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)