# Setting debug scrappy for pycharm

Tags: debugging, scrapy, pycharm, anaconda

I have installed `scrapy 1.5.1` on `windows 8.1` using `conda 4.5.11` with:

```
conda install -c conda-forge scrapy
```

I am running Pycharm:

```
PyCharm 2018.2.4 (Professional Edition)
Build #PY-182.4505.26, built on September 19, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b8 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 8.1 6.3
```

I have set my project interpreter to anaconda's python:

[image]

Furthermore, I have setup a debug configuration and pointing my working directory to my spider's project directory:

[image]

I have setup a breakpoint in my spiders code. However, when I press debug I get the following error on my console output:

```
"C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.2.4\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 54316 --file "C:/Program Files/Anaconda3/Scripts/scrapy.exe" crawl btctalkSpider -o items.csv
pydev debugger: process 632 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 182.4505.26)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\tokenize.py", line 390, in find_cookie
    line_string = line.decode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 2: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.2.4\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1664, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.2.4\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1658, in main
        globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
      File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.2.4\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1068, in run
        pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
      File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.2.4\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 11, in execfile
        stream = tokenize.open(file)  # @UndefinedVariable
      File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\tokenize.py", line 454, in open
        encoding, lines = detect_encoding(buffer.readline)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\tokenize.py", line 431, in detect_encoding
        encoding = find_cookie(first)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\tokenize.py", line 395, in find_cookie
        raise SyntaxError(msg)
    SyntaxError: invalid or missing encoding declaration for 'C:/Program Files/Anaconda3/Scripts/scrapy.exe'
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 0):

You should use cmdline.py from scrapy as "Script path"

Found response here: [How to use PyCharm to debug Scrapy projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21788939/how-to-use-pycharm-to-debug-scrapy-projects)

[image]