# What is unicode_literals used for?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I get a weird problem with `__future__.unicode_literals` in Python.  Without importing `unicode_literals` I get the correct output:

```
# encoding: utf-8
# from __future__ import unicode_literals
name = 'helló wörld from example'
print name
```

But when I add the `unicode_literals` import:

```
# encoding: utf-8
from __future__ import unicode_literals
name = 'helló wörld from example'
print name
```

I got this error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf3' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Does `unicode_literals` encode every string as an utf-8?
What should I do to override this error?

---

<sub>See also: [Python, Unicode, and the Windows console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419) for a related, Windows-specific problem.</sub>

Comment: The import **only has an effect on Python 2**; it makes Python 2 behave as Python 3 does when it comes to string literals. It makes your code cross-Python-version compatible.

Comment: The issue is with your terminal, it is unable to display non-ascii characters.

Comment: Since you are using `print` as a *statement* you must be using Python 2 instead; I've removed the `python-3.x` tag that threw me off.

Comment: @roippi: no, it is perfectly capable of showing already-encoded UTF-8 bytes. It is not *communicating* to Python that it is using UTF-8.

Comment: Yes, I could have phrased that better.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Your terminal or console is failing to let Python know it supports UTF-8.

Without the `from __future__ import unicode_literals` line, you are building a byte string that holds UTF-8 encoded bytes. With the string you are building a `unicode` string.

`print` has to treat these two values differently; a byte string is written to `sys.stdout` unchanged. A `unicode` string is encoded to bytes first, and Python consults `sys.stdout.encoding` for that. If your system doesn't correctly tell Python what codec it supports, the default is to use ASCII.

Your system failed to tell Python what codec to use; `sys.stdout.encoding` is set to ASCII, and encoding the `unicode` value to print failed.

You can verify this by manually encoding to UTF-8 when printing:

```
# encoding: utf-8
from __future__ import unicode_literals
name = 'helló wörld from example'
print name.encode('utf8')
```

and you can reproduce the issue by creating unicode literals without the `from __future__` import statement too:

```
# encoding: utf-8
name = u'helló wörld from example'
print name
```

where `u'..'` is a unicode literal too.

Without details on what your environment is, it is hard to say what the solution is; this depends very much on the OS and console or terminal used.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer as of 2023 (and beyond)

You code is very likely to support Python >= 3, right ?

So you can drop this statement.

`__future__.unicode_literals` was intended for backward/forward compatibility with Python 2 <->3 (read the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__future__.html)).

Since Python 2 [isn't supported upstream](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/), there are little reason to keep this forward compatibility code. (unless you care for users of long term support distribution, of course)