# Adding exception to "AttributeError" python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

So, I have some tweets with some special characters and shapes. I am trying to find a word in those tweets by converting them to lower case. The function throws an "AttributeError" when it encounters those special characters and hence, I want to change my function in a way that it skips those records and processes others.

Can I add exception to "AttributeError" in python. I want it to act more like an "iferror resume next"/Error handling statement.

I am currently using:-

```
def word_in_text(word, text):
try:
    print text
    word = word.lower()
    text = text.lower()
    match = re.search(word, text)
    if match:
        return True
    else:
        return False
except(AttributeError, Exception) as e:
    continue
```

error post using @galah92 recommendations :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 2220, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas\src\inference.pyx", line 1088, in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas\lib.c:63043)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "<input>", line 3, in word_in_text
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 146, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

I am new to Python and self learning it. Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean `except`?

Comment: I tried `except` but it does work either.

Comment: What is the logic causing the `AttributeError`? Have you considered using the built in function `hasattr()`?

Comment: [Just strip you string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276764/stripping-everything-but-alphanumeric-chars-from-a-string-in-python) before using `lower()`.

Comment: I tried stripping, seems like the column dtype=object instead of string, Can you suggest how do I work it out? and example of a tweet is **CANCION! You &amp**

Comment: Take a look at the answer I posted. It works with the tweet you gave.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.IGNORECASE` flag when you `search()`.
That way you don't need to deal with `lower()` or exceptions.

```
def word_in_text(word, text):
    print text
    if re.search(word, text, re.IGNORECASE):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

---

As an example, if I run:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals # see edit notes
import re

text = "CANCION! You &amp"
word = "you"

def word_in_text(word, text):
    print(text)
    if re.search(word, text, re.IGNORECASE):
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(word_in_text(word, text))
```

The output is:

```
CANCION! You &amp
True
```

---

**EDIT**

For Python 2, you should add `from __future__ import unicode_literals` at the top of your script to make sure you encode everything to UTF-8.
You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23370025/what-is-unicode-literals-used-for).

Comment: for me it says:- **text = "CANCION! You &amp"
<class 'xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError'>:reference to invalid character number: line 1, column 113**

Comment: I tried but it still gives the same error. I am using Eclipse for python, do you think that can be the issue?

Comment: Unlikely. Can you edit you question and add a full log of the error?

Comment: You've got a `TypeError` (last line in log). Make sure `text` and `word` is of type `string`. You can Try `print type(text)` and `print type(text)` before the `search()` line.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It shows the type as Unicode. I have added the **from __future__ import unicode_literals**. As a way around I tried to strip the text of Unicode characters but it gives the following error **UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 16-19: ordinal not in range(128)**.  Do you have any suggestions? I have all the tweets in a data frame using pandas

Comment: Not particularly, but I believe your answer is right [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31137552/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-at-special-name).