# Encoding Differences (Umlaute) between Python Versions

Tags: python, character-encoding, raspberry-pi

I am trying to send an email including an attachment via Python from my Raspberry Pi.
The following code (email.py) works when I'm using `sudo python3 email.py` but does not via `sudo python email.py`.

```
######WRITE EMAIL AND SEND
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "de_DE")

attachment = 0
fromaddr = 'MAIL@gmail.com'
toaddr = ['MAIL@gmail.com']
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = ", ".join(toaddr)
msg['Subject'] = 'ÄÖÜäöü'
body = 'Ääüäöü'
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain',_charset='latin-1'))
filename = 'Picture'
for file in os.listdir('/path/to/Pictures/'):
    if file.__contains__('.png'):
        a_file=file
        attachment = open('/path/to/pi/Pictures/'+a_file, 'rb')
part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
part.set_payload((attachment).read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename= %s' % filename)
msg.attach(part)
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(fromaddr, 'Password')
text = msg.as_string()
print ('# Sending mail')
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
server.quit()
print('# Mail Sent')
```

The Error I am getting when using the python method is:

`SyntaxError: Non ASCII character \xc3 in file email.py on line XX but no encoding declared; see htttp://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details.`
The Umlaute `ÄÖÜ...` are causing the problem.

I know that different python versions use different encodings as default and I python3 uses utf-8.
Somehow with `python email.py`another encoding is used and I don't know how to change it.

I would like to know where I'd have to add specific encoding instructions into the code so that the code works on both python versions.

Comment: You can try including `from future import __unicode_literals__` at the top, then Python 2 will treat all strings as unicode. [See this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23370025/what-is-unicode-literals-used-for).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python2 uses ASCII as default encoding. However, you can define the encoding to be used.

Add the following line to your script in order to hint your python to use a utf-8 encoding.

`#coding=utf-8`

You are not getting any error in case python3 because it uses utf-8 as default encoding.