# IndexError: List Index out of Range when grabbing gmail text

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, gmail, steam

I'm using this code to login to my gmail account and retrieve text from an email from steampowered.

```
else:
      g = gmail.login(emailAddress, emailPassword)
      # Check for emails until we get Steam Guard code
      for i in range(0, 3):
        mails = g.inbox().mail(sender="noreply@steampowered.com", unread=True)
        if mails:
          mail = mails[-1]
          mail.fetch()
          #print re.findall(r"you'll need to complete the process: ([A-Z0-9]{5})", mail.body)
          guardCode = re.findall(r"you'll need to complete the process: ([A-Z0-9]{5})", mail.body)[0]
          mail.read()
          mail.delete()
          g.logout()
          return guardCode
        else:
          time.sleep(3)
```

I get a

> IndexError: List Index out of Range

At this line:

```
guardCode = re.findall(r"you'll need to complete the process: ([A-Z0-9]{5})", mail.body)[0]
```

This is because

```
re.findall(r"you'll need to complete the process: ([A-Z0-9]{5})", mail.body)
```

Returns

```
[]
```

So the list is empty. Why is it empty?

This is the format of the email:

> Are you logging into Steam using a new browser or Steam app? Here’s
>   the Steam Guard code you’ll need to complete the process:  XXXXX  <---- I need this

**EDIT:** Gmail is a custom python module from [here](https://github.com/charlierguo/gmail).
**EDIT #2:** Here's a better representation of the email:

> Dear XXX,
>
> Are you logging into Steam using a new browser or Steam app? Here's
>   the Steam Guard code you'll need to complete the process:
>
> XXXXX
>
> If you havenâ€™t recently tried to login to Steam from the device
>   located at XXXX (US), someone else may be trying to access
>   your account. You can view more info about this login attempt online.
>
> If you suspect someone else may be attempting to access your account,
>   please either:

Answer (score 2):

Problem is because of `’` in `you’ll`. It isn't a normal single quote `'`.

```
>>> s = "Are you logging into Steam using a new browser or Steam app? Here’s the Steam Guard code you’ll need to complete the process: XXXXX"
>>> re.findall(r"you’ll need to complete the process: ([A-Z0-9]{5})", s)
['XXXXX']
```

Comment: Wow. How did you guess that?

Comment: How do I combine this with `mail.body`?

Comment: replace `s` in the above code with `mail.body` (ie, the variable which stores the input you want to work with.)

Comment: No I mean that I'm grabbing the value XXXXX from an email, so I can't set mail.body to a string, it has to be the body of the email.

Comment: sorry i don't know what do you mean. I just answered `So the list is empty. Why is it empty?` question only. Wait, someone will surely solve your problem.

Comment: I'm sorry. I was the one at fault here. I changed the code to this `guardCode = re.findall(r"you’ll need to complete the process: ([A-Z0-9]{5})", mail.body)[0]` but now I'm getting a SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2', no encoding declared, see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for more.

Comment: put `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top in your python script file. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10589674/3297613

Comment: Lol, now it's giving me the same error again. (IndexError: List Index out of Range)

Comment: Could a new line be a problem?

Comment: could you provide contents of the input string variable?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. I just ended up removing all line breaks and making the email body text as one entire string. Thanks to everyone who helped!

```
str = re.sub('\s+',' ', mail.body)
guardCode = re.findall(r'to complete the process: ([A-Z0-9]{5})', str)[0]
```