# Python Syntax error: non-ASCII

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

I keep getting an error and I'm not sure on how to fix it.

The Code line:

```
if not len(lines) or lines[-1] == '' or lines[-1] == '▁':
    lines = list(filter(lambda line: False if line == '' or line == '▁' else True, list(lines)))
```

Output:
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file prepare_data.py on line 512, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

Comment: I know your question isn't about the code you've written but that needs some reworking too.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?, give a better context of the code, which of these two lines is the 512?, maybe you have problems with the encoding and you need use utf8 in your code

Comment: Also, what version of Python are you using? UTF-8 is the default encoding for source files starting in 3.4. (Thanks @IljaEverilä)

Comment: The relevant PEP: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3120/, and a somewhat similar Q/A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289474/working-with-utf-8-encoding-in-python-source

Answer (score 2):

The error message tells you exactly what's wrong. The Python interpreter needs to know the encoding of the bytes in the string which displays as a funky underscore.

If you want to match [U+2581](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2581/index.htm) then you can say

```
.... or lines[-1] == '\u2581':
```

which represents this character in pure ASCII by way of a Unicode escape sequence.  If you want to match a regular ASCII underscore, that's ASCII 95 / [U+005F](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/5f/index.htm); here are the two characters side by side for easy comparison and possible copy/paste:

```
U+2581 ▁  _ U+005F
```

The linked PEP in the error message instructs you *exactly* how to tell Python "this file is not pure ASCII; here's the encoding I'm using".  If the encoding is UTF-8, that would be

```
# coding=utf-8
```

or the Emacs-compatible

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
```

If you don't know which encoding your editor uses to save this file, examine it with something like a hex editor and some googling.  The Stack Overflow [character-encoding](/questions/tagged/character-encoding) tag has a [tag info page](/tags/character-encoding/info) with more information and some troubleshooting tips.

In so many words, outside of the 7-bit ASCII range (0x00-0x7F), Python can't and mustn't guess what string a sequence of bytes represents. https://tripleee.github.io/8bit#e2 shows 21 possible interpretations for the byte 0xE2 and that's only from the legacy 8-bit encodings; but it could also very well be the first byte of a multi-byte encoding. In fact, I would guess you are actually using UTF-8, which represents this character as the three bytes 0xE2 0x96 0x81; but without also seeing the character rendered as something resembling an underscore, there would be absolutely no way to guess this for a human, either.

Comment: I adapted this as an answer to the question which I'm thinking this should be closed as a duplicate of; https://stackoverflow.com/a/50831670/874188

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I haven't tested it, but I think it might solve your encoding problem. Your code needs some improvements for readability, remember the Zen of Python please.

```
def filter_line(line):
    if not line or line == '▁':
        return False
    else:
        return True

lines = [line.encode("utf-8") for line in lines]

if not lines or lines[-1] == '' or lines[-1] == '▁':
    lines = list(filter(filter_lines, list(lines)))
```

Comment: The encoding problem is in the code. You have copy/pasted the problematic character into your code, too.