# What is the SyntaxError builtin practically used for in python?

Tags: python, error-handling, syntax, syntax-error

What is the point of the `SyntaxError` builtin in python? It doesn't seem to have any practical use because `SyntaxError`s are found by the python interpreter **before** the code is run. Example:

```
try:
    &@!5_+ #SyntaxError
except: pass
```

This fails with a `SyntaxError` because the `SyntaxError` is found before it can be handled. Now this works and fails silently, like intended:

```
try:
    raise SyntaxError
except: pass
```

However, I have never seen a `function` or `class` or *anything* raise a `SyntaxError`. So why does this exist so easy to use and catch when the only use seems to be raising it pointlessly? Is there someplace that python raises a `SyntaxError` that it can be caught? Or does it just exits in the builtin scope just to be there?

Comment: It can be used to handle items parsed using `ast.literal_eval` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#SyntaxError) is self-explanatory:

> Raised when the parser encounters a syntax error. This may occur in an import statement, in a call to the built-in functions `exec()` or `eval()`, or when reading the initial script or standard input (also interactively).

Comment: So `import ...`, `__import__(...)`, `exec(...)` and `eval(...)`? Is that it?

Comment: @EthanK you can also encounter errors with encoding such as [SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589620/syntaxerror-non-ascii-character-xa3-in-file-when-function-returns-%c2%a3)

Comment: But can you catch them?

Comment: @EthanK i believe that you can catch any exception if it's a product of some operation/computation/process.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to attack this question is to search for how this exception gets raised in practice. I have the CPython source code already downloaded, so I did

```
find . -type f -name "*.py" | xargs grep "raise SyntaxError"
```

We see that there is a utility script that does file conversions that raises a syntax error if it doesn't see the magic byte in the correct place. Additionally, the `xml` library uses them in parsing XPath expressions.

This suggests that it is meant to be used by user code that deals with parsing other things as well. A Google search for "raise SyntaxError" shows many results of this being used in this way.

I'm not terribly familiar with the Python internals, but I assume being able to handle an error in paring source code the same way they handle other errors makes things nicer. Plus `eval` etc. have to raise something, as the docs and the previous answer state.

Comment: Nice technical answer! Thanks for doing so much looking around!

Answer (score 1):

There's very rarely a use for using `SyntaxError` in your program. It's usually only used for the python interpreter when it encounters invalid syntax.

The only case I can think of that you would ever catch a `SyntaxError` is if you are using `exec` or `eval` on an unknown value. For example, if you were executing user input, then the input may be invalid and you would need to catch the `SyntaxError`.