# Python 2.7: How to print this character?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to print this character "¥" in python 2.7.
Here is my code:

```
test = "¥"
print(test)
```

I execute this code and I get this error message:

> SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file main.py on line 5, but
>   no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for
>   details

How to print this character?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct way to define Python source code encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728891/correct-way-to-define-python-source-code-encoding)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xa3' in file when function returns '£'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589620/syntaxerror-non-ascii-character-xa3-in-file-when-function-returns-%c2%a3)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the following line in the top of file:

```
# -*- coding: <encoding> -*-
```

Next time when you run this file Python will know what the encoding of that character is.

It will look like this, assuming you use utf-8.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
test = "¥"
print(test)
```