# Django make messages error 'Python' unknown

Tags: python, django, internationalization, gettext

I am trying work with internationalization and install the GNU gettext tool for generate messages.

- In my settings/base.py I use the i18n context processor in the directive TEMPLATES:

  `TEMPLATES = [`

  ```
  {
  'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
  'DIRS':[os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
  'APP_DIRS': True,
  'OPTIONS' : {
      'context_processors':[
          'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
          'django.template.context_processors.debug',
          'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
          'django.template.context_processors.media',
          'django.template.context_processors.static',
          'django.template.context_processors.tz',
          'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
      ],
  },
  ```

  `},
  ]`
- I also use the LocaleMiddleware in my settings/base.py

  `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (`

  ```
  'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
  ```

  `)`
- I also specify the languages that I want use in my settings/base.py:

`from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _`

```
LANGUAGES = (

    ('en', _('English')),
    ('ca', _('Catalan')),
    ('es-co', _('Spanish')),
)
```

- My predetermined `LANGUAGE_CODE` is `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'`and I specify the locale folder so (also in settings/base.py):

  `LOCALE_PATHS = (
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
  )`
- For the behavior of my app, i implement this url i18n_patterns function:

`from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns`

`urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^$', home, name='home'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)`

With this, my app in my local server home page redirect to /en or /ca

Of side of my templates, I am testing the translation on some tags html like

and

using this two template tags: trans for translate a single line and blocktrans for paragraphs

- Is here when I use gettext library (I build and install in my machine) and in the the moment of generate my message, I get this output error:

  `(tb_test)➜  my_project git:(master) ✗ python manage.py makemessages -l ca
  CommandError: errors happened while running xgettext on __init__.py
  language` `Python' unknown
  (tb_test)➜  my_project git:(master) ✗`

The output says that there is a problem on **init**.py ...
The most files named **init**.py I have them empty ..
On which files should I focus for this message of `Python' unknown

I'm newbie in python, my apologies.
Best Regards, thanks

Postdata: I am interested in learn about of internationalization in Django apps, and I did want follow this sample of this great tutorial 
http://www.marinamele.com/taskbuster-django-tutorial/internationalization-localization-languages-time-zones

This page describe a bit the steps that I describe here in my post. 
Thanks

Comment: new to python and starting with gnu gettext? Respect ;-)
Anyway, could you please add more information to your question? Do you have some code for us? I read your question twice but still don't know what your're exactly doing...

Comment: Of course @aronadaal. I'm not too much newbie although I am just following an example of Internationalization in which use gettext library. In my main post of this question I complete more details. Thanks

Comment: @aronadaal I've edited my question for have more details about it. Thanks

Comment: Strange. I think I found something similar here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370035/django-makemessages-errors-unknown-encoding-utf8  The problem could be similar to yours: what is inside of the init.py files?

Comment: Inside of my __init__.py files there is not nothing. The most files are empty. That problem that you refer me is similar, but the error of they is about of  utf-8 codification type inside of __init__py files. My error is more strange (I think so),  this of language python unknown

Comment: How did you install gettext or xgettext and what OS are you running?

Comment: @JustinHamade I install gettext of this way. I've dowload from https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/, unzipped, and I build the package with ./configure, make and make install commands using the following source http://www.marinamele.com/taskbuster-django-tutorial/internationalization-localization-languages-time-zones#inter-translation

Comment: @BernardoGarcia Sounds like your install is missing Python support which I can't reproduce.  If you are running a linux distro I would recommend installing a pre-compiled binary from your distro's package management.  For ubuntu 'sudo apt-get install gettext'  For OS X install from brew http://brewformulas.org/Gettext