# Django makemessages command generates error: "xgettext: Non-ASCII string"

Tags: python, django, internationalization, django-i18n, xgettext

I have a simple django project. I am attempting to translate the site into Russian. Here is my settings.py file:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'n_gc#7lsv48h-b$)9aw6eer6z$zia#@da=bdwgova1=6u!8uvh'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'omefx.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR+'/omefx/templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'omefx.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}



LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', ('English')),
    ('ru', ('Russian')),
)

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR +'/omefx/', 'locale'),
    'locale',
    # os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'locale'),
)
# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR+'/omefx/', 'static'), )
```

In my template I have a {% trans %} tag for testing:

```
<h2>{% trans '160+ TRADING INSTRUMENTS' %}</h2>
```

When I run the command below:

```
python manage.py makemessages -l ru
```

I get the following error:

```
xgettext: Non-ASCII string at ./myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/webencodings/__init__.py:64.
          Please specify the source encoding through --from-code or through a comment
          as specified in http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html.
```

Side Note: No apps in my project. My Locale folder path is omefx/omefx/locale as well as my templates folder.

Comment: what is the output in the console if you put this In your settings.py `print("Media: ", MEDIA_ROOT)`

Comment: /Users/Brigadier90/Projects/omefx/media
+ error message from before

Comment: What is your `LANG`, `LC_CTYPE` etc. env variables? Make sure you use some utf-8 encoding there.

Comment: I do not know. Where do I find those?

Answer (score 8):

I found a fix in a similar question.
Find the directory in which the files are that produce the error and ignore them when exceute the manage.py makemessages command.

So if for example you're venv folder produces the error use the makemessages comand like this:

```
manage.py makemessages -l ru -i venv
```

Link to that other question:
[Django makemessages errors Unknown encoding "utf8"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370035/django-makemessages-errors-unknown-encoding-utf8)

Answer (score 0):

You should run the command with `--ignore venv` or `-i venv` ignoring virtual environment (myvenv in your case) as shown below, then the error is solved. *You can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370035/django-makemessages-errors-unknown-encoding-utf8/76668362#76668362) explaining why the error occurs in detail:

```
python manage.py makemessages --ignore ru myvenv
```

```
python manage.py makemessages -i ru myvenv
```

The commands below also work:

```
django-admin makemessages --ignore ru myvenv
```

```
django-admin makemessages -i ru myvenv
```