# Localization: django-admin compilemessages skip venv

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-admin, django-1.11

I am using localization in `Django 1.11` application. I can exclude the virtual environment folder and `node_modules` folder while adding the messages in message file using `-i` option like:

```
django-admin makemessages -l 'no' -i venv
django-admin makemessages -d djangojs --locale no -i venv -i node_modules
```

After adding the translations I am compiling messages using:

```
django-admin compilemessages
```

It processes `django.po` files of all installed packages located in virtual environment folder. Thus it takes longer time to finish compiling translations.

I did not find any argument parameter to skip a specific path from `compilemessages` command in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#compilemessages).

Is there any option to skip the `venv` or specific path from `compilemessages`?

Comment: I have the same question, and am surprised the ignore flag is possible for `makemessages` and not `compilemessages`. Have you found any solution in the meantime? This [thread](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30133) recommends moving the `venv` folder out of the django project, but the possibility to ignore it in the `compilemessages` command would be preferable.

Comment: No. I have not found any solution yet.

Answer (score 20):

Django 3.0 added --ignore option

```
django-admin compilemessages --ignore=cache --ignore=outdated/*/locale
```

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-compilemessages-ignore

---

*(Method #2)*

BEFORE THAT THE BEST HACK I FOUND TO IGNORE THE VENV IS:

```
cd to project
python ../manage.py makemessages  (jumping one directory up)
python ../manage.py compilemessages
```

(This little hack from a workmate avoids compiling the venv .po)

---

*(Method #3)*

And also before, another workaround was trying the more complicated way of using the **--exclude** flag

```
usage: django-admin compilemessages [-h] [--version] [-v {0,1,2,3}]
                                    [--settings SETTINGS]
                                    [--pythonpath PYTHONPATH] [--traceback]
                                    [--no-color] [--locale LOCALE]
                                    [--exclude EXCLUDE] [--use-fuzzy]
```

[github](http://www.searchcodeserver.com/file/056a3c5007e48a5ece4196c281877236b7b6e909/django/django/core/management/commands/compilemessages.py#44)

```
        parser.add_argument(
            '--exclude', '-x', action='append', default=[],
            help='Locales to exclude. Default is none. Can be used multiple times.',
        )
```

Unfortunately this is for locales, but it is the only thing I found so far

From [these internal communications](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29973) on the development of Django, I can see the ignore flag has been copied from makemessages to compilemessages for a future version

For my own usage I used (excluding es and en)

```
django-admin compilemessages --exclude=sw --exclude=sl --exclude=sk --exclude=km --exclude=sv --exclude=ko --exclude=sq --exclude=sr --exclude=kk --exclude=ka --exclude=es_MX --exclude=fa --exclude=fy --exclude=fr --exclude=en_AU --exclude=ne --exclude=nb --exclude=nn --exclude=nl --exclude=id --exclude=az --exclude=io --exclude=ar --exclude=ia --exclude=kn --exclude=it --exclude=is --exclude=vi --exclude=af --exclude=my --exclude=mr --exclude=uk --exclude=pl --exclude=ur --exclude=mk --exclude=mn --exclude=ml --exclude=he --exclude=hi --exclude=hu --exclude=hr --exclude=en_GB --exclude=pa --exclude=cs --exclude=fi --exclude=cy --exclude=sr_Latn --exclude=os --exclude=pt --exclude=ja --exclude=bs --exclude=br --exclude=bn --exclude=ast --exclude=bg --exclude=hsb --exclude=dsb --exclude=ro --exclude=es_CO --exclude=ru --exclude=et --exclude=eu --exclude=zh_Hant --exclude=zh_Hans --exclude=be --exclude=eo --exclude=el --exclude=da --exclude=de --exclude=pt_BR --exclude=ta --exclude=ca --exclude=te --exclude=es_AR --exclude=th --exclude=lt --exclude=lv --exclude=tr --exclude=tt --exclude=es_VE --exclude=lb --exclude=gl --exclude=ga --exclude=gd --exclude=udm--exclude=sw --exclude=sl --exclude=sk --exclude=km --exclude=sv --exclude=ko --exclude=sq --exclude=sr --exclude=kk --exclude=ka --exclude=es_MX --exclude=fa --exclude=fy --exclude=fr --exclude=en_AU --exclude=ne --exclude=nb --exclude=nn --exclude=nl --exclude=id --exclude=az --exclude=io --exclude=ar --exclude=ia --exclude=kn --exclude=it --exclude=is --exclude=vi --exclude=af --exclude=my --exclude=mr --exclude=uk --exclude=pl --exclude=ur --exclude=mk --exclude=mn --exclude=ml --exclude=he --exclude=hi --exclude=hu --exclude=hr --exclude=en_GB --exclude=pa --exclude=cs --exclude=fi --exclude=cy --exclude=sr_Latn --exclude=os --exclude=pt --exclude=ja --exclude=bs --exclude=br --exclude=bn --exclude=ast --exclude=bg --exclude=hsb --exclude=dsb --exclude=ro --exclude=es_CO --exclude=ru --exclude=et --exclude=eu --exclude=zh_Hant --exclude=zh_Hans --exclude=be --exclude=eo --exclude=el --exclude=da --exclude=de --exclude=pt_BR --exclude=ta --exclude=ca --exclude=te --exclude=es_AR --exclude=th --exclude=lt --exclude=lv --exclude=tr --exclude=tt --exclude=es_VE --exclude=lb --exclude=gl --exclude=ga --exclude=gd --exclude=udm --exclude=zh_CN  --exclude=ky --exclude=zh_TW --exclude=no --exclude=pt_PT  --exclude=hy
```

Comment: If you're getting the error: "CommandError: This script should be run from the Django Git checkout or your project or app tree, or with the settings module specified." , you might need to set [`LOCALE_PATHS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#locale-paths) in your settings.

Comment: Github link broken

Answer (score 8):

As others already stated, in Django 2.x sadly there are only hacks to deal with this. (Django 3.0 finally added the `--ignore` to `compilemessages`.)

The one I found to be most transparent was to debug into `compilemessages` and look at the `subprocess` calls it issues. From that you can derive the direct calls to the `msgfmt` tool.

For our comparably simple project, `makemessages` collects the `*.po` files in `locale/$LANGUAGE/LC_MESSAGES/django.po`. Then `msgfmt` would put the generated `*.mo` in the same folder. So we just wrote a script to perform steps like this:

```sh
set -e

django-admin makemessages --all --ignore venv

# HACK: Run msgfmt manually instead from "django-admin compilemessages"
# because the latter also searches venv.
msgfmt -o locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
msgfmt -o locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
msgfmt -o locale/hu/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo locale/hu/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
# ...add other languages as needed.
```

This is of course incredibly clumsy but easy to understand and extend.

Answer (score 5):

Django 3.0 added --ignore option

```
django-admin compilemessages --ignore=cache --ignore=outdated/*/locale
```

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-compilemessages-ignore

Answer (score 3):

Using ignore option

```
python manage.py compilemessages -i "venv*"
```

this command worked for me. Make sure, venv should be in double quotes(""), not single quote('')

Comment: If you are using docker, make sure the path is relative to the pwd, when I tried `./manage.py compilemessages -i "/app/.tox*"` it didn't work, I needed to use `./manage.py compilemessages -i ".tox*"`

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this command manually from python, here is the correct syntax for ignoring the virtualenv:

```
management.call_command("compilemessages", ignore_patterns=[".venv/*"])
```